# NoReverseMatch at in django

Tags: python, django

I am making an online quiz site using bootstrap and django. I want to make a system where the admin enters an OTP value that acts as password of every user(I haven't yet made the admin part hence using a constant int value for development purposes only).

I have made a form but it is throwing me an error saying :
NoReverseMatch at /class10.html/testlanding.html/
Reverse for 'validating_user' not found. 'validating_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[image]

the following is the files :

**url.py :**

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.homepage, name = "home page"),
    path ("class10.html/" , views.class10 , name = "Class 10th"),
    path ("class12.html/", views.class12, name ="class 12"),
    path ("class10.html/testlanding.html/", views.validating_users, name ="pre test info"),
    path ("class12.html/testlanding.html/", views.validating_users, name ="pre test info"),
    path ("class10.html/testlanding.html/testinstruction.html/", views.test_instruction, name ="pre test info"),
    path ("class12.html/testlanding.html/testinstruction.html/", views.test_instruction, name ="pre test info"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse , HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import login_form
# Create your views here.

def homepage(response):
    return render (response,"main/index.html",{})

def class10 (response):
    return render (response, "main/class10.html", {})

def class12 (response):
    return render (response, "main/class12.html", {})

def validating_users (response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = login_form(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Name = form.cleaned_data['Name']
            passwd  = int(form.cleaned_data ['Password'])
            if passwd== 1234 :
                return HttpResponseRedirect ( "main/testinstruction.html")
    else :
        form = login_form()
    return render (response , "main/testlanding.html", {} )

    #return render (response , "main/testlanding.html",{})

def test_instruction (response):
    return render (response , "main/testinstruction.html", {})
```

**forms.py :**

```
from django import forms

class login_form (forms.Form):
    Name = forms.CharField( max_length= 250)
    Passwd= forms.IntegerField()
```

**testlanding.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!--the normal html head and other tags -->
        <body>
           
            <!--navbar--> 
        
            <!-- Login from -->
            <div class="container marketing">
        
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'validating_user' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <h1 class=" h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        
        
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
        
                    </div>
        
                    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit" ">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    
    
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**Update:**
I was successfully able to solve it. The main problem was I was using the view method definition in the {% url '' %} tag, but django needs you to rather put in the name attribute that is mentioned in the path of the document.
Refer :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: It's looking for a url in definition in `urls.py` with `name="validating_user"`.  But there aren't any.

Comment: so basically if i call something like this it looks for the name tag instead of looking for the actual view function name that handles it 
??

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The `{% url %}` template tag uses the `name` attribute of the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, the url is incorrect. I should be:

`<form method="POST" action="{% url 'pre test info' %}">`

Since that is the name you established for that path.

In respect to your URL configuration file: it is a mess, the **name** property should be unique, and if you have several URLs pointing to the same view you should pass some args in the URL so the view can distinguish them.

You should read the documentation on how Django manages URLs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: thanks a lot it actually worked and I looked into the documentation and realized what I was doing wrong appreciate it